# How to customize the categories page in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the layout of the page as per my custom wordpress theme but i don't know which file should be edited for customizing the woocommerce categories page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it partly .. wordpress category comes from more then one files. so you have to change it file by file and manage it sequence ..

Files related category find in template folder of woocommerce ..

Comment: i just copied the woocommerce template files to woocommerce folder in my theme and tried to change to archive-product.php file but its having no effect. can you please tell me which hook or which part should i modify to put my code

Comment: you have to take all files out of template folder, which is located in your theme directory . and delete your empty template folder .

Comment: and then you can get your changes .